# Mousewheel handler for child element and his parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousewheel

I made a jQuery plugin that replaces default scrollbar with my own and handles mousewheeling and dragging the bar events.

When I put the content with my scrollbar into another content with my scrollbar, and then if I use mousewheel on the child content, the parent content wheels as well.

It happens because I bound mousewheel event listener to both child and parent contents, and when my mouse over them both, it triggers both event handlers.

**The problem is that I need to wheel only the child content without affecting the parent.**

Do you have any tips how to resolve that? Dragging scrollbar event works ok.

Comment: Please share some code you are using so we can reproduce your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the propagation of the event. This will stop the event from bubbling up the DOM tree and triggering on parent elements.

http://jsbin.com/yelijelowa/1/edit?js,output

```
$('body').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
  alert('Body scroll');
});

$('.child').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  alert('Child scroll only');
});
```

If you comment out the `e.stopPropagation();` line you'll note that both alerts fire.

Documentation:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)
- [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: A 1000 thanks. It worked))) Seems like I don't have enough reputation to thank you(

Comment: You should be able to select this as the 'best answer', which will generally let others know your problem has been solved. You unlock the upvoting function with more [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).